# Python - Creating a 11 digit number list generator

Tags: python

I am a beginner and was wanting to create an 11 digit number list generator, currently, I have tried this.

```
numberList = list(range(01000000000, 02000000000))
```

also tried this one as well

```
def createList(r1, r2):
    return list(range(r1, r2+1))

r1, r2 = 01000000000, 02000000000
print(createList(r1, r2)
```

)

Obviously, It shows an error regarding prefix for octal literals, or to be exact ,

> Python version 3.9 does not support this syntax. It requires '0o'
> prefix for octal literals

So tried it without the zeros and the PC crashed as it ran out of memory.

So need something that can generate the list without crashing the whole computer.

Comment: Write it as a generator with `yield`

Comment: That's a lot of stuff to hold in memory.  If you just want to output it, then use a normal loop.

Comment: It's easier to put your expected outputs first - eg. what's the `digits` that you want? Prob. you are not looking for a `generator` solution.   Also make it clear `what is the requirements` for this 11-digits?

Comment: Leading zeroes are not allowed in python, since they might be confused with octal number syntax in older python versions

Comment: Why did you think you needed to convert your range into a list? range objects work very well for many use cases.

Comment: what do you expect the output to be

Answer (score 2):

Since your requirement is not clear, here I just try to assume that you want to make a *11-digit number* by stating the **starting** and **ending** number/digits to the function.

Try this and modify to fit your needs as the final function.

```
In [15]: def create_digit(start, end):
    ...:     return list(range(start, end))
    ...: 

In [16]: create_digit(1, 12)
Out[16]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

In [17]: ''.join(str(x) for x in create_digit(1, 12))
Out[17]: '1234567891011'

In [18]: ''.join(str(x) for x in create_digit(1, 11))
Out[18]: '12345678910'
```